# Am I misusing binomial random variable to represent probability of a student answering questions correctly?

Tags: probability

Suppose a student is taking a test. There are four questions and each question has four possible answers. Let $q_i \in \lbrace 0,1\rbrace$ denote whether the student gets the $i$th question correct. Let $$S = \big \lbrace (q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4) |q_i \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace ,\forall i = 1,2,3,4\big \rbrace $$ denote the set of possible successes and fails for the student. The student guesses at random.  I want to know the probability the student passes, where passing means getting $k$ correct. Let $X \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ denote whether the student passes or not.

**One Way to Answer the Question:**

There are $4^2 = 16$ possible outcomes because we have for separate variables and each can take on one of two values. Furthermore, let $W$ denote the number of chances the student has to get $k$ correct.

$$ W = \sum^4_{i=k} \binom{4}{i}$$

So then, the probability the student passes should be

$$\Bbb P (X=1) = \frac{\sum^4_{i=k} \binom{4}{i}}{16}$$

**My Question**

Is there a way to answer this question using a binomial random variable?

Since each question is like a trial, shouldn't I be able to write

$$\Bbb P (X =1) = \sum^4_{i=k} \binom{4}{i} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^i\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{4-i} $$

But this doesn't yield the same results and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are sixteen *distinct* outcomes but theses are **not** each *equally probable*.   You cannot measure probability as a comparison of counts of outcomes *unless* they are equally probable; you have to account for the different "weight" of each (aka probability mass).

A way to do this is to note that there are actually $4^4$ *equally probable* outcomes, many of which are just *not* considered distinct.   For each of the four questions, there are three wrong answers and one right one.   Hence the additional factors.

$$\mathsf P(X{=}1) ~=~\dfrac 1{4^4}\sum_{i=k}^4 \dbinom{4}{i}\color{navy}{(1^i\cdot 3^{4-i})}$$